# Error running App with apache HTTP libs

Tags: android-studio, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm getting a Fatal Error when running my App on Emulator from AndroidStudio:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
```

That's my build.gradle for Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.htw.roishachor.dbplanupdater"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;


public void myMethod() {
       CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try{
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(new URI(INITIAL_URL));
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent())); ....
```

A weird thing. I don't know if it has anything to do with it - my libs and build folder are not visible from AndroidStudio, I can only see them in Explorer.
I saw in a tutorial, that I have to right click on each .jar file and add it as library.
Does it has anything to do with it? The jars are inside my lib folder, but as mentioned, I could only add them trough my explorer

Answer (score 0):

review docs [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

make those chgs to gradle.build plus add mavenCentral to top level gradle.build ....

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and then check for namespace collisions where you have to use the apache versions (HC4 suffx)

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGetHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPostHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPutHC4;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntityHC4;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntityHC4;
```

after making those changes , you should get predicted result.